# Keep getting wrong result C# compiler

Tags: c#

This is my code below. I made it to check names and show certain messages. When I run this code on an online C# compiler it works fine but when run locally it skips to the `else` statement right away.

Any help appreciated. Thanks

```
bool isUserWrong = true;

while (isUserWrong)
{
    Console.Write("Insert your name");
    string userInput = Console.ReadLine();

    if (userInput.Equals("XYZ",  StringComparison.OrdinalIgnoreCase))
    {
        Console.WriteLine("{0} Sorry not you again!", userInput);
        isUserWrong = true;
    }
    else if (userInput.Equals("ABC", StringComparison.OrdinalIgnoreCase))
    {
        Console.WriteLine("{0} Youre the one!!!!", userInput);
        isUserWrong = false;
    }
    else
    {
        Console.WriteLine("{0} Sorry wrong name :(", userInput);
        isUserWrong = true;
    }
    Console.ReadLine();
}
```

Comment: Obviously, the `ReadLine()` method is returning some string other than `"XYZ"` or `"ABC"`. But you haven't provided a good [mcve] that reliably reproduces the problem, so there's not any way for anyone here to help you _fix_ whatever problem exists.

Comment: I could reproduce the problem when using a Read() instead of a ReadLine().

Comment: seems to work fine

Comment: I tried it and it works fine - you don't need the second Console.Readline unless you always want to have to press return twice.

Comment: @Kevin Ford  I know it works fine somehow its not working locally for me. Any if statement which contains strings is not working for me locally. I am new to C# so did'nt learn much about debugging. Thanks for checking it up for me :)

Comment: @Peter I am sorry if i was not being clear. My problem is if else statement is not working for me properly. As I showed above the code works in online compilers but not locally. If else statement not giving me the right O/P instead its giving me only else statement result for all the inputs i type. Hope I am being clear now :/

Comment: _"Any if statement which contains strings is not working for me locally."_ -- I assure you, the `if` statements are working correctly, as are the string comparisons. If the code isn't doing what you want or expect, it's because your expectations are incorrect. You need to use a debugger and look at the strings. Based on your description, most likely the input strings use different characters than the comparison string. Try e.g. `StringComparison.CurrentCultureIgnoreCase` instead of `OrdinalIgnoreCase`, in case the user input is for some reason using alternative versions of the characters.